# What can make weird changes into opcached framework code?

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-5.6, fpm

I encountered strange error with my `php-fpm 5.6.30` with `OPcache v7.0.6-dev` on ubuntu server. I got error at `/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php` file concerning `array_keys(static::$levels)` code in it:

> array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

The `static::$levels` property is defined in the top of `Logger.php` file as array:

```
protected static $levels = array(
    self::DEBUG     => 'DEBUG',
    self::INFO      => 'INFO',
    self::NOTICE    => 'NOTICE',
    self::WARNING   => 'WARNING',
    self::ERROR     => 'ERROR',
    self::CRITICAL  => 'CRITICAL',
    self::ALERT     => 'ALERT',
    self::EMERGENCY => 'EMERGENCY',
);
```

This code was installed via composer and never edited manually, so there is no reasons for the file to be changed.

When I look at my `laravel.log`, I see that something has changed the code behaviour, so lines at the log changed their format:

```
[2018-05-16 00:19:22] production.INFO: blabla
[2018-05-16 00:20:04] production.[object] (DateTimeZone: {"timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"}): blablabla
```

The key fact is that when I opened the file using `nano`, added a comment line into it and saved, the bug disappears. It means that the wrong code was in the opcache, not in the code of the framework.

To conclude, the bytecode of `Logger.php` was somehow changed and php saw object with `DateTimeZone` objects in it rather than an array of strings.

The question is - how could the cached bytecode be changed without being totally crashed? What on earth can do this? Can high memory consumption lead to such unexpected changes?

Comment: It should be mentioned, that by 00:19:23 one 20-minutes cron job had just finished.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue in our project (php 5.6.30, opcache v7.0.6-dev). To solve the problem we analyzed the opcache settings and found that [interned_strings_buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.interned-strings-buffer) was 4Mb. Raising this value to 64 Mb we solved the problem.

Comment: side note: "b" stands for "bit", while "B" stands for "byte", so you rather wanted to say "4MB" etc...

Comment: How did you guess that? Why is this particular settings value so important?

Comment: We install an opcache monitor on our server and we notice that when the problem occurs the `interned_string_buffers` usage was full. I Follow this [article](https://www.scalingphpbook.com/blog/2014/02/14/best-zend-opcache-settings.html) for further information about Opcache settings